# How to shorten decimal output in bash?

Tags: pipe, bc, floating-point

Right now I am working on an assignment that involves advanced piping, and one of the questions involves calculating a percent and shortening it to 3 decimal places.  I've managed to calculate the percent:

`echo "$ERRORS" / "$TOTAL" \* 100 | bc -l`

which gives the correct output: 2.64905226881102814400

ERRORS and TOTAL are both environment variables containing integers.

But I don't really know how to modify this command to only output 2.649 instead of the full number.  I know there is a way to use something called scale with bc to shorten to a certain number of decimal places but I tried `echo scale=3; "$ERRORS" / "$TOTAL" \* 100 | bc -l` and it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In general "_it didn't work_"  expresses nothing much more than frustration. You should explain what happened or what didn't happen, how that differed from your expectation, and the precise text of any messages generated. (The reason for comparing against your expectation is so that we can validate whether it's your expectation or the code that needs addressing.)

Comment: In the spirit of "advanced piping": pipe the output from bc into `| xargs printf '%.3f\n'`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$ ERRORS=1153 TOTAL=43525
$ echo "scale = 3; $ERRORS * 100 / $TOTAL" | bc
2.649
```

instead. See how in this case, `scale = 3` is being fed to `bc` to set the scale variable *of `bc`*, which is the number of digits that *it* keeps after the radix upon division, and how we did the multiplication by 100 *before* the division.

Note that it's truncation, not rounding. 8 * 100 / 9, will become 88.888, not 88.889 for instance.

If your shell supports floating point arithmetics (ksh93, zsh, yash), you can also do:

```
$ printf '%.3f\n' "$((ERRORS * 1e2 / TOTAL))"
2.649
```

(though note that in zsh and ksh93, it's critical the contents of those variables be controlled as that would constitute a command injection vulnerability if not. We use `1e2` (a floating point 100 while `100` is integer) instead of `100.` as in ksh93, `100.` wouldn't work in locales that use `,` as the decimal radix).

Or you could use `awk`:

```
$ awk -- 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", ARGV[1] * 100 / ARGV[2]}' "$ERRORS" "$TOTAL"
2.649
```

Both of which would give you 88.889% (or possibly 88,889 depending on the locale) for 8 out of 9.

Comment: @PCRevolt If Stéphane Chazelas answered your question, you should accept his answer:  [Click on tick mark on top-left
of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242).